# Jenkins Pipeline Best Practice: All in groovy or call powershell script

Tags: powershell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We have a jenkins build job. It has multiple steps with powershell, bat,plungins ... calls. The program is a windows application.
I want to change the job to a pipeline file which is in the scm.

I'm asking me what is the best practice:
Convert all the build steps to groovy pipeline script or call a powershell script (also in scm) for each step.
I also want to replace the bat-scripts also with groovy or powershell.

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't well formed question. It involves recommendations and practices. I'm not gonna flag it, because you can still try to enhance it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for "yae" and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for "nay".

Comment: Also, I'm gonna share my personal opinion nontheless: I would recommend that you start with just calling your existing scripts from Jenkinsfile. Once you have that, try to move to Jenkinsfile itself. There will be a kind of regression, so nothing will get broken, and even if you need to stop and refocus, you'll still have working CI stack.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you should minimize the use of external resources as long as the language you work offers you the same functions.

So : for Jenkins pipeline groovy should be the choice. I would do there the build "orchestration", sandbox preparation, test machines and containers starting, calling APIs for external tools like SONAR, Nexus, TFS, Octopus, Artifactory.

If your build requires extra build steps like installing things on windows machines, registering DLLs, IIS manipulation, powershell would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding on [iftimie-tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7103406/iftimie-tudor) answer. I want to minimize the calls to External tools such as Jenkins or Bamboo in our case so we wrapped the build scripts into a build script and a common script. I won't weigh in on whether you should use groovy or powershell as that depends on the team and you. You can split it up into multiple scripts if needed and use both groovy and powershell. Here is what it would look like in powershell:

MyBuildScript.ps1

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1)]
[string] $CommonTools = '.\tools\jenkins\Common.ps1',
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
[switch] $WhatIf
# LOAD MY COMMON FUNCTIONS 
. $CommonTools
# BUILD 
## i.e MSBuild
# TEST 
## i.e NUnit
# PACK 
## i.e. OctoPack
# PUSH 

if($WhatIf) {

} else {
## i.e push to Octopus
}
```

Making the build script testable locally can be useful.

MyBuildScript.Tests.ps1

```
Import-Module .\lib\pester.x.x.x\tools\Pester.psm1 -Force

Describe "Test the Build Script" {
   It "Builds everything" { 
   }
}
```

Making the common tools testable locally can be useful as well.

Common.Tests.ps1

```
Import-Module .\lib\pester.x.x.x\tools\Pester.psm1 -Force

Describe "Test the Build Function" {
   It "Works" { 
   }
}
```

Ideally the scripts are source controlled so you can track the changes as you convert each portion of the build as [filip-malczak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219585/filip-malczak) mentioned in the comments. If someone breaks the build, they fix the build. They add a feature and it's not building, fix the build script. The feedback loop is as quick as possible lining up with the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html). If tests are needed, add them.